# Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine in C# .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

This question may be asked many times.. but the scenario i am working on is bit diff and yet very simple..I am getting above error and not getting any solution so far..here is my client code where i get the error while "Read" highlighted in Bold.. Please help..thnx in advance.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Timers;

namespace ClientRequest
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {

            TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting.....");

            IPAddress[] objLocalAddr = null;
            String strHostName = "";
            int port = 2425;

            strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
            IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);
            objLocalAddr = ipEntry.AddressList;

            tcpclnt.Connect(objLocalAddr[0], port);


            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
            Console.Write("Enter the string to be transmitted : ");

            String str = Console.ReadLine();
            Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

            ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] ba = asen.GetBytes(str);
            Console.WriteLine("Transmitting.....");

            stm.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);

            byte[] bb = new byte[100];
            **int k = stm.Read(bb, 0, 100);**                
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(bb[i]));               

               tcpclnt.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);
         }
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before executing the Read function do this:

```
if( stm.CanRead && stm.DataAvailable )
{
    int k = stm.Read(bb, 0, 100);
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(bb[i]));               
}

tcpclnt.Close();
```

Comment: Hi HyperDev, thnx for the solution..but it still not working as stm.CanRead is true and goes to read inside the if condition..and while 'Read' the same error appears.also please note 'stm.DataAvailable' proerty is not available so i am putting only stm.CanRead in if condition..Thnx